# Auto-submit form with PHP action via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Forgive me if this question is naive. I'm new to JavaScript and am learning my way through some setbacks with a form I'm using to display data.

An `icao` code is passed to the `#depicao` `<select>` menu via `$_GET['icao']` in the JavaScript code at the bottom of the script. On page load, the `<select>` menu is populated with the `$_GET['icao']` value.

After the `#depicao` `<select>` menu is populated, I'd like the form to automatically submit itself *with* its populated value. My train of thought is that if I include

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

as the *last line* in the script, I can get the script to submit itself *after* it loads with the `$_GET['icao']` value. Unfortunately, this hasn't been working, however.

**NOTICE:** The code contains **multiple** `<input type="submit" name="submit">` buttons. I believe that this is the culprit.

See code below.

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo actionurl('/schedules/view');?>" method="post">
<div id="tabcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#depapttab" onclick="formReset()"><span>Via departure airport</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#arrapttab" onclick="formReset()"><span>Via arrival airport</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="depapttab">
        <select id="depicao" name="depicao">
        <option value="">Select All</option>
        <?php
        $exclude = array(13, 18, 19, 22); // Airport IDs found in phpVMS_airports not to be included in the dropdown menu
        if(!$depairports) $depairports = array();
            foreach($depairports as $airport) {
                if(!in_array($airport->id, $exclude)) { // Exclude values in the above array from the dropdown menu
                    echo '<option value="'.$airport->icao.'">'.$airport->icao.' - '.$airport->name.'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find Flights" />
    </div>
    <div id="arrapttab">
        <select id="arricao" name="arricao">
            <option value="">Select All</option>
        <?php
        $exclude = array(13, 18, 19, 22); // Airport IDs found in phpVMS_airports not to be included in the dropdown menu
        if(!$depairports) $depairports = array();
            foreach($depairports as $airport) {
                if(!in_array($airport->id, $exclude)) { // Exclude values in the above array from the dropdown menu
                    echo '<option value="'.$airport->icao.'">'.$airport->icao.' - '.$airport->name.'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find Flights" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="findflight" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formReset() {
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
function setSelectedIndex(s, valsearch) {
    // Loop through all the items in drop down list
    for (i = 0; i< s.options.length; i++) { 
        if (s.options[i].value == valsearch) {
            // Item is found. Set its property and exit
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("depicao"),"<?php if(isset($_GET['icao'])) { echo $_GET['icao']; } else { echo 'Select All'; } ?>");
document.getElementById("form").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to have the form auto submit itself after it's populated with a value passed from `$_GET['icao']` onload.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez That's correct. Currently, the user has to click the `Find Flights` button for the form to submit itself. I would like for the form to submit itself automatically onload <i>with</i> the data that was passed into the `<select>` field via `$_GET['icao']`

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez The default `<option>` value is set to `Select All`, which displays all data.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez On occasion, yes; a user may select that option. In this scenario, a value is passed to the form via `$_GET` and that value is what needs to be submitted.

I've set up the form such that the `$_GET` value successfully populates the `<select>` field, but I'm having trouble getting the form to automatically submit itself <i>after</i> that happens.

Comment: @GlutenFreeSeaMonster have you checked your console for errors ?

Comment: So, you want to do something like "if ( $_GET["icao"] == "all" ] then auto_submit() else dont_autosubmit" ?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Exactly. I can get the `<select>` field to automatically populate itself with the `<option>` value that matches the `$_GET['icao']` value, but once it's populated, I can't get it to auto-submit.

I fear that it's because there are multiple `<input type="submit" name="submit">` buttons.

Comment: Cannot run your code. What is echo actionurl('/schedules/view')? Gives me error (you didn't post it).

Answer (score 0):

**Form Auto Submission Confusion ?:**

> After the #depicao  menu is populated, I'd like the form to **automatically submit itself** with its populated value.

How I understood you was that you want the form to be submitted automatically when the select menu is populated ? I think you meant when the user chooses a selection, it should submit automatically. If this is what you mean. Please add a `onchange="//submitfunction()"` onto the `<select>` tag